# jquery-isotope not rendering iframe with Youtube) properly after filter or layout change

Tags: jquery, css, youtube, jquery-isotope

I am using a demo example for jquery isotope and on the whole this is a great plugin.

However I am experiencing a really strange issue when filtering or rearranging content on resize or layout changes.

If I add an iframe with Youtube embed, after layout changes, the content is rendered with part of another content box in the layout.

I have tried it with both Youtube and Vimeo embeds and I can only reproduce it on Youtube.

Here is an snippet of the code:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
itemSelector: '.box',
animationEngine: 'best-available', //CSS3 if browser supports it, jQuery otherwise
duration: transitionDuration,
containerStyle: {
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'visible'
}, 
masonry: {
        columnWidth: columnWidth,
        isFitWidth: true
}
  });

  div class="grid">
<div class="box class1">
    Odd future 3 wolf moon twee...
</div>

<div class="box class2">
    Bushwick marfa craft beer, wes anderson...
</div>

<div class="box class3">
    Try-hard thundercats food truck, ...
</div>

<div class="box class3">
    <div style="border:1px solid #eee">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/36224081?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="320" height="200" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="box class1 ">
    Odd future sriracha fixie disrupt, ...
</div>

<div class="box class3">
    <div style="border:1px solid #eee">
        <img src="thumbnail.png" style="width:100%; height:auto" alt="thumbnail" />
    </div>
    box-view.pdf. This might help with your spellings.
</div>

<div class="box class2">
    <div style="border:1px solid #eee">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/smiFk6KHr_8?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="320" height="200" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

...
```

On first load both show perfectly:

After sort, the Vimeo looks perfect like this:

However, the Youtube version is rendered with part of the image from another box:
[image]

[image]
[image]

I don't know of this is a youtube or isotope.js issue. Does anyone have a fix for this or have experienced it.

I can partly fix it with the following code, although usealy instead of the video image I get a black screen:

```
$grid.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
console.log( 'arrangeComplete with ' + filteredItems.length + ' items' );
$("iframe").each(function(index,value){

        $(value).hide().fadeIn(0.01);
});
 });

$grid.on( 'layoutComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
$("iframe").each(function(index,value){

        $(value).hide().fadeIn(0.01);
});
 });
```

however this is not very nice and takes time to render especially with the default css transitions.

Any thoughts.

**EDIT**

After trying to do a fiddle unsuccessfully, I tried the same code in Chrome (had been using IE11 before) and the issue does not exist even without the fix which leads me to the conclusion it is an IE issue, which is probably not surprising

Still no closer to solving the issue, but I can't replicate it in jsfiddle so maybe I need some hack for ie with youtube iframes?

Comment: Show us a jsfiddle or post a link.

Comment: I can't recreate it in jsfiddle. see my update.